# special subset of certain groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking at the properties of group and I was able to prove that the set H = {n ∈ Z : |n| = 1} is a group under multiplication that is closure , associativity, inverse and identity elements is in H. Now, I have to show that if this set is subgroup of Z. I have read in the abstract algebra book on how to do subgroup test. And the following is the properties:

(i) H is closed under the operation from Z;

(ii) H contains the identity element e from Z; and

(iii) H contains the inverse of each of its elements.

I know that $Z$ is group under addition and not group under multiplication. The question just asked that if $H$ is subgroup of $Z$? now to check the properties for subgroup , for closure , do I have to show that H is closed under multiplication or addition?

Comment: for the information, I am using book Abstract Algebra: An Inquiry-Based Approach by Authors :Jonathan K. Hodge, Steven Schlicker, Theodore A. Sundstrom.

Comment: To show that $\{-1,1\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, you have to determine whether it is a subgroup under addition since that is the operation of the group $\mathbb{Z}$. The fact that $\{-1,1\}$ is a group under multiplication is not relevant here.

Comment: The problem you want to solve is not precisely stated. What is the group operation on $Z$? That is not here. In fact $Z$ has infinitely many group operations, some of them making $H$ its subgroup. That being said, it is a common convention that when we talk about $Z$ as a group, and we don't specify the group operation, then the group operation is implicitly assumed to be the standard addition.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Thank you for clarification, that's why I was confuse because the question does not specify the group operation of Z. It is helpful to know that if the group operation is not specified , presumption is standard addition.